# Parse ios sdk default sign up not working

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am new to parse. I am using the ios sdk for an app and trying to implement login and signup. I downloaded the latest version (1.2.21). I am using PFSignUpViewController to implement sign up. I tried subclassing the controller to customize it but I am seeing a number of problems. First, I can't seem to be able to change the field placeholder names for username or password. The password field doesn't even show the placeholder at all; it's empty. Second, I can't turn on the additional field. No additional field shows up despite the customization code. Does anyone know what could cause this? Or Could it be a bug in the parse framework?
- Below is my subclass of PFSignUpViewController.

```
#import "QSignUpViewController.h"

@interface QSignUpViewController ()

@end

@implementation QSignUpViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.fields = PFSignUpFieldsUsernameAndPassword |
    PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton | PFSignUpFieldsAdditional;

    self.signUpView.usernameField.placeholder = @"Email";
    self.signUpView.passwordField.placeholder = @"Password";
    [self.signUpView.additionalField setPlaceholder:@"Phone Number"];

    [self setEmailAsUsername: YES];
    //self.signUpView.emailAsUsername = YES;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE -- the issue should be corrected in the latest iOS SDK 1.3

There are bugs with subclassing the PFSignUpViewController with the current sdk (version 1.2.21) you can work around the problem by reverting back to version 1.2.19 of the sdk parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-library/1.2.19 -- at least until 1.2.22 is released.

As for your placeholder text issue -- the UITextFields in the PFSignUpView are using the attributed placeholder property. The below snip of code will set the usernameField place to "Email" for example.

```
PFSignUpView *signUpView = [self signUpView];
[[signUpView usernameField] setAttributedPlaceholder:nil];
[[signUpView usernameField] setPlaceholder:@"Email"];
```

Answer (score 0):

## import "ViewController.h"

## import "Parse/Parse.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  [self mySignUp];

}

- (void)mySignUp {

  PFUser *user = [PFUser user];

  user.username = @"name";

  user.password = @"1";

  user.email = @"email address";

  [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

  ```
  if(!error) {

      NSLog(@"Successfully signed up");

      _myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@!", user.username];
  }

  else {

      NSLog(@"Successfully signed up");
      _myLabel.text = @"You are not logged in";

      NSLog(@" %@", [error userInfo][@"error"]);


  }
  ```

  }];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

@end